Scaling an icon gradient leaves an outline
Edit: This is only an issue on Safari. Chrome does not have this.
I've been attempting to add a gradient to an icon when the user hovers over it, like below. However, when it scales, it leaves a small, but noticeable, outline around. How would I fix this?


.links i {
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.icon-link:hover i {
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(74, 151, 232), rgb(57, 57, 217));
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <!--Icon init-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
</head>

<body style="background-color:black">

  <div class="links">
    <!--Email-->
    <a href="https://example.com" class="icon-link" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
      <i class="material-icons" style="margin-left: 0;">email</i>
    </a>
    <!--GitHub-->
    <a href="https://example.com" class="icon-link" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
      <i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i>
    </a>
    <!--Discord-->
    <a href="https://example.com" class="icon-link" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
      <i class="fa-brands fa-discord"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>





Could you share a screenshot of the issue? Running the code, I cannot see any outline on scale.

@AlvaroMontoro I added a screenshot. You gave me the idea of trying it on chrome, and there is no outline. Only on Safari.

I am trying on Safari, but still I cannot replicate the issue :(

@AlvaroMontoro weird… maybe I need to update? If you can’t see it, I should be fine then haha

I tried in a second monitor, and still nothing. Just out of curiosity, try replacing this line: background: linear-gradient(rgb(74, 151, 232), rgb(57, 57, 217)); with this one: background: linear-gradient(rgb(74, 151, 232), rgb(57, 57, 217)) 50% 50% / calc(100% - 2px) calc(100% - 2px) no-repeat; Let me know if something like that works.

@AlvaroMontoro I ran the code on a different computer and it looks fine... it must just be mine?
P.S. I ran that code you gave and I don't see that outline, but it makes the GitHub logo have square-ish corners.
